# Problem with dual channel back-to-back mosfet AC dimmer

Tags: mosfet, ac, dimmer

I'm having a problem with a two channel mosfet dimmer that I'm constructing. When I had only one channel (T1_signal and Load_1_Live) populated on the PCB in the schematic below the dimmer works fine. But when using two channels they interfere with one another. If channel 1 is fully on and channel 2 fully off then channel 2 turns on during the top half of the AC sinewave. The reverse is also true (if you swap places with 1 and 2 in the previous sentence).

Below the schematic is another example where channel 1 on the dimmer is set to about 20% intensity (mosfets on for about 2ms). In the first scope image channel 2 on the dimmer is set to 100% intensity (mosfets always on). Magenta (3) on the scope is measured at the drain of Q1 and cyan (2) is the T1_signal. As seen the top half of the sinewave does not get dimmed/chopped to 20%/2ms. The second scope image shows the same scenario except with the intensity of channel 2 on the dimmer set to less than 20% (mosfet on time for channel 2 less than the 2ms on time for channel 1) and now the upper half of the sinewave gets correctly dimmed.

I tried putting a diode between R9 and GNDA, thinking the problem had something to do with current moving from the gate of the mosfets that are on to the gate of the mosfets that should be off thus turning them on, but that didn't change anything.
Can anyone figure out what is going on here?

Thanks in advance, 
Lars E

[image: Schematic]
[image: Schematic]
[image: Schematic]

Comment: You have short circuit! GNDA shorts Q2 and Q4 sources, while drains are effectively the same point. Those two MOS are in parallel. You need two separate GATE_DRIVE/GNDA power supplies, one for each channel.

Comment: Is there no way to separate it using diodes? The GATE_DRIVE/GND power supply takes up quite a bit of space on my PCB so it would be really nice to only have one..

Comment: Wouldn't adding a diode between the mosfet source and GNDA (anode to GNDA) in both mosfet couples eliminate the short?

Comment: I am afraid there no way to do the trick you are talking about. Just think of the following: 1) Q1-s/Q2-s and Q3-s/Q4-s can be at different potentials up to +/-320V each other depending on individual on/off status. 2)GATE_DRIVE has to be some 15V above GNDA in order to drive or be-ready-to-drive gates.  3)How can GATE_DRIVE be at the same time  15V above two nodes which are 320V apart?

Comment: @carloc Hmm, I see the problem.. can D1 be shared (not duplicated) between the two gate supplies?

Comment: Oh yes I think that's no problem, you can save one diode.

Comment: Thanks alot @carloc, I don't see a way to mark a comment as a correct answer but thanks again for the help!

Comment: You are welcome! I don't have time to write and format the above comments in something good enough to be an answer, but I am not after reputation and things, your "Thank you" is quite  enough to me. If you wish feel free to answer yourself to your question, I think that's allowed